# Yii хранить состояние чекбокса в сессии?

Tags: yii

Есть правая колонка. Предположим, там есть чекбокс. Как запомнить его состояние? При клике post-запрос отправлять? В PHP можно было бы в сессию записать. А здесь как?

upd

дошел до такого 
view

```
 <?php
 if (isset(Yii::app()->session['data'])) 
 $check = Yii::app()->session['data'];
 else $check = false;
 echo $check;
  echo CHtml::checkbox('my-checkbox', $check, array('id'=>'my-checkbox-id')); ?>
            <?php
  Yii::app()->clientScript->registerScript('my-event-listener',"
  $('#my-checkbox-id').change(function(){
      $.post(
          'check',                 //url
          {                                    //data
               myval: $(this).is(':checked')
          }
          );
      });
  ");
  ?>
```

controller

```
public function actionCheck() {
  if(Yii::app()->request->isPostRequest)
  {
    if(isset($_POST['myval']))
    {
       // save value to DB        
        $session = new CHttpSession;
        $session->open();
        $session['data'] = $_POST['myval'];
        print_r(Yii::app()->session['data']);
    }
  }
  else
    throw new CHttpException(400,
      Yii::t('app', 'Invalid request. Please do not repeat this request again.'));
}
```

визуально true и false $check присваиваются. а чекбокс всегда нажат. такое ощущение что чтобы не было в нем он считает это текстом и нажимает чекбокс

Comment: Можно GET, можно POST. Никто вас не ограничивает :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

прошла такая проверка

```
 if (isset(Yii::app()->session['data']) && Yii::app()->session['data']==='true')
                $checkme = 1;
            else
                $checkme = 0;
            echo $checkme;
            echo CHtml::checkbox('myval', $checkme, array('id' => 'my-checkbox-id'));
```

что тоже в принципе странно